# mutate swift array from objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Given the following class

```
@objc class Foo: NSObject {
  var myArray = [Bar]()
}
```

I'd like to add to array variable from objc.

```
Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo.myArray addObject: bar];
```

myArray is typed as NSArray not NSMutableArray, so has no method addObject.

Comment: And what happens when you try?

Comment: @AshleyMills: I added a sentence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
@objc class Foo: NSObject {
  var myArray = [Bar]()

  func addBar(newBar: Bar) {
    myArray.append(newBar)
  }
}
```

then

```
Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo addBar: bar];
```

According to the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) this is the better way to write it, as you're not accessing a method on a property of `foo`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this as well:

```
@objc class Foo: NSObject {
    var myArray = NSMutableArray()
}
```

And then from Objective-C:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo addBar:bar];
```